# C++ explicit function signatures

Tags: c++, type-conversion, wrapper

I would like to create a helper wrapper against variant type structure, so that type signature would call the necessary transformations, like:

```
variant CreateVariant(bool value);
variant CreateVariant(int value);
variant CreateVariant(char *value);
```

The problem is bool and int, since they are implicitly convertible types...

So for code like:

```
variant a = CreateVariant((BOOL)value);
variant a = CreateVariant((__int64)value);
variant a = CreateVariant(1);
```

There are some problems.

How can I design a clean wrapper if I need to process bool as boolean and unigned/signed int/uints/longs/longlongs as integer types?

For class constructors I can use `explicit` keyword, but I have to use functions int the code I'm updating.

Comment: I think that the problem here is that the `BOOL` type is just a `typedef` for `int`.  I don't believe that there's any way to disambiguate the two in this case, though I could be wrong.

Comment: I fail to see the problem. I tried overloading a function with `bool`, `int`, and `__int64_t`, and it was able to distinguish between each one every time.

Comment: @howardh- Note that the example uses `BOOL` rather than `bool`.  `BOOL` is a Microsoft `typedef` for `int`, hence the problem.

Comment: I want to avoid cases where unspecified variable type is silently and implicitly down-converted to say bool, if it need to be explicitly converted to int. So that there is a compile time error.

Comment: BOOL was probably bad example as it's a int typedef, and I think I can do nothing about it. But what if someone passes float?

Comment: @Coder, can you modify your question which addresses the new queries ?

Comment: Add a template `CreateVariant`, it will catch everything that does not match a non-template version exactly.

Comment: "There are some problems." Please mention which problems.

Comment: You are actually showing only the unimportant details, and hiding the information  that actually matters: what would the interface of your variant be? Is it a variant over a fixed set of types or do you intend on implementing type erasurelikeboost::any? What do you want to use the variant for? How?

Comment: Why don't you read up on the overload resolution rules in C++? There is no problem. Here, memorize this: overload works by identifying a set of candidates for a function call (functions that can be called at all with those arguments). From among those candidates, there has to be exactly one which is at least as good a match as the others in every argument, and strictly better than the other candidates in at least one argument. If there is no such function or more than one, it's a diagnosable error.

Comment: "There are some problems" is not helpful. What are the problems? Be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments are alluding to, the answer to your question lies in differentiating between "bool" (the real boolean type) and BOOL (the MS typedef of int).

On the broader subject, though, I've done the exact same thing in code. If you're on the MS platform, consider using _variant_t or CComVariant: both do basically what you want. I ended up doing my own conversion class with a template which passed through to the underlying parent class (in this case _variant_t) by default, and adding specializations for constructor types which did not have a built-in conversion to the MS class type. You will have to add specializations for each type for which there is not a conversion in the underlying type, but usually that's not too bad.

I should add:

The advantage of doing it this way is that there will be no implicit conversion. If the type matches an explicit override, it will be used. Otherwise, it will match the template, and get passed to the MS type. If the MS type cannot accept the type passed, you will get a compile-time error, and know what you need to address.